# Why is uitextfield not outputting optional?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I printed the force unwrapped text values of my textfields in my viewdidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print("loaded")
    print(passwordInput.text!)
    print(emailInput.text!)
}
```

but instead of crashing with:

```
loaded
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

it printed:

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDhpX.png)

please tell me why it didn't crash with an optional nil but "" if you know!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of `UITextField` is an empty string. so even if you have not typed anything the value is ""

If you want to check:

```
if let validPass = passwordInput.text {
   print("It is not optional")
} else {
   print("It is optional")
}
```

And you will see that output is "It is not optional" 
If you want to check whether it is empty or not:

```
if let validPass = passwordInput.text, !validPass.isEmpty {
    print("It is not optional or not empty")
}
```